# Working with transparency: View behind transparent view should only shine through and not overlap

Tags: ios, uiview, transparency

I'm currently working with transparency and I'd like to have the following effect:

[image: Line is behind transparent UIView]

As you can see the line takes the full width of the view. There are some transparent UIViews also on this screen. The line seems to be below the transparent UIView and if it overlaps it has another color, because of the transparent UIView above. When there is no overlapping the line get its normal color.

How can I get this effect?

I tried to set the background of the UIView to transparent, but it didn't helped. The line has its normal color and doesn't interact with the transparency. Furthermore I tried to change the transparency of the view itself but with the same wrong result.

[image: some tries to replicate the effect]

The rectangle above is done with code

```
UIView rectangle = new UIView (new CGRect (10, 10, 200, 120));
rectangle.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA (204,115,225, 50);

UIView line = new UIView (new CGRect (0, 105, 320, 1));
line.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;

View.AddSubview (line);
View.AddSubview (rectangle);

line.SendSubviewToBack (rectangle);
```

the rectangle below is created in iOS designer.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why are you sending rectangle to back, your question reads like it should be in front...

Comment: rectangle is not even a subview of line. This line is incorrect and probably what is causing the problem.

Comment: I wanted to send the line behind the rectangle. I tried a few things even without this code line. But I didn't get it managed to get my result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The z-order of the subviews was correct in my case. Depending on the color the effect I want is possible or not. So I made the following:

Choose another background color for the lavender color rectangles and adapt the alpha transparency to look similar. So something like this:

```
rectangle.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA (245/255.0f,227/255.0f,249/255.0f,0.7f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its all about the z order of the Subviews.

```
line.SendSubviewToBack (rectangle);
```

is probably not what you want.

If you add the line with its normal red color and add a UIView that has its alpha dropped to e.g. 0.5, then you should get the effect you want.

Comment: Now I tried to create my *rectangle* with normal background color (without transparency). Then I set the transparency of the view to some value and I didn't used the `SendSubviewToBack` method. The line has always its full color and the transparency has no effect. The z-order should be imho parent `UIView`, *line*, *rectangle* (ascending order -> the last one is the front most `UIView`). Isn't that done with the normal order of adding the subviews to my parent `UIView`?